# Can I remove transparent pixels from a layer with a different blending mode in Photoshop cc14?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, background-removal, blend-modes

If I have a layer with a white background and I want to remove it, I can often just change the blending mode to Screen or Overlay and it ends up exactly the way I want it. However, I often want a different blending mode for the remaining visible pixels. Of course I could just select the area I want, but it takes a long time to achieve the exact same effect, especially when using overlay.

So I was wondering if there's a simple way to keep the layer exactly as it looks with a blend mode, even when converting it back to Normal?
Hope that made sense

Comment: Short answer: No. Longer answer, and i do mean longer, would be maybe.

Comment: as @joojaa said it would be a long answer, Interested to know what could be ;) ... as far as I know we could achieve the same effects with some hacks.

Comment: You can not "remove" a white background changing blending modes.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand what you mean. If you want to make all the white pixels transparent, you can use layer styles.

1. Double-click the icon of the layer. The Layer Style window will open.
2. In *Blending options>Blend if>This layer*, option-drag* the white slider all the way to the left:
   [image: Slider]

These sliders determine the range of brightness values that the layer will be visible in. You can read more about that here:
[Specify a tonal range for blending layers](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/layer-opacity-blending.html#specify_a_tonal_range_for_blending_layers).

When you click OK, only the dark pixels will be visible. You can select any blending mode you want.

*This is on a mac. On different operating systems, you may have to use other keys than option.

Comment: 'Option' on a Mac is 'Alt' on a PC.  Just like 'Command' on a Mac is 'Ctrl' on a PC.  [See this for more](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/what-where-is-option-key-on-mac-what-is-apple-key-3462401/)